# Scrape data from TikTok?

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping

So I'm trying to **scrape** data from TikTok, however something goes wrong.
Sometimes it returns full page, sometimes this:

```
{"statusCode":200,"contentType":"text/html","content":""}
```

and even sometimes returns

```
Redirecting to (tiktok url)
```

It never actually redirects to mentioned URL.

Is there any way to **scrape** the main page constantly?
This is my current code:

```
$pageurl = "https://www.tiktok.com/@".$_GET["username"];
$ch = @curl_init($pageurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240');
    
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing requests with CURL, redirects are not followed by default.  To make it follow redirects, the `FOLLOWLOCATION` setting is needed, as such:

```
$ch = @curl_init($pageurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

For the empty response, you *might* be getting an error, so you should be checking for that:

```
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}
```

or it could just be that the error is on their end and you should just retry until you get a non-empty response.

Comment: That works fine, however, after some time it still returns **{"statusCode":200,"contentType":"text/html","content":""}** instead of main page. Why does it happen?

Comment: if there is no error and you are getting back a `200` response, it seems that that is simply what they are sending back.  I would guess that they are either rate limiting you or detecting that you are scraping them.